# How to put chapter table of contents on a separate page?

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, minitoc

I would like to put chapter title on a separate page. I use the titlesec package for this. But I would also like to chapter's table of contents on the same separate page (i.e. the chapter title page). Currently, I use minitoc for chapter table of contents. How do I put this minitoc in titlesec?

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\titlerule[1pt]%
\vspace{1pt}%
\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\Huge}
[\newpage] % creates the new page
```

Comment: I  am not  sure but `titletoc` could be better.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `\minitoc` before the `\newpage`:

```
[\minitoc\newpage]
```

Comment: Thanks! it works but it then shifts the main table of content of the book to a separate page and also it shifts the abstract etc to another page.

Comment: That's what you asked for. You want chapter titles on a separate page. The table of contents, etc. also have a chapter title, so they are on their own page.

You can put a separate \titleformat{chapter} without the last line containing the \newpage before the \tableofcontents and the other frontmatter stuff, and then the full thing before the first chapter.